# Local proxy intermediate?

Tags: networking, proxy

I switch between many proxies (different institutes, home, etc.). Some of the programs I use have individual proxy settings (such as Dropbox). For some reason they don't seem to understand the environment variables `http_proxy`, etc. very well.

I want an intermediate program that listens all requests on a specific port, and routes them through a proxy. Then I can point all my programs to use this intermediate local proxy, and when I change location, I only have to change the settings of the intermediate program.

I got the idea from CNTLM, but CNTLM only works for Microsoft NTLM networks.

How can I set this up?